# Find the value of P(Y >= X | Y >= 12)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables each with uniform distribution from $[0,100]$. I know that
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y \ge 12] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[Y \le 12] = \frac{88}{100}
$$
I'm just confused on how to find $\mathbb{P}[Y \ge X \cap Y \ge 12]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a uniform distribution, $P(Y\geq X)=\frac{Y-0}{100}=\frac Y{100}$.

So, we have $$P(Y\geq X)\cap P(Y\geq12)=\frac1{100}\int_{12}^{100}\frac Y{100}dY=\frac1{20000}Y^2\bigg\vert_{12}^{100}=0.4928$$

Comment: Your notation is questionable, but the idea is okay.  So indeed:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(12\leq Y\cap X\leq Y)&=\int_{12}^{100}\int_0^y\tfrac 1{100^2}~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\\&=\tfrac{308}{625}\end{align}$$